# Windows XP restarting automatically

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'm unable to get why Windows XP operating system restarting automatically after showing showing an option "Start window normally", but despite of clicking on that option it is again getting reboot, showing this option again.

Could anyone please tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run `chkdsk` or some similar tool on it. You can boot from a bootable CD, for example you can use [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), and run NTFS4DOS, and then you can run `chkdsk /f`.

Comment: Will my data get formated by doing this or not? I'm little unsure.

Comment: No, it will not hurt your data. Most of the time the restart is caused by a filesystem error (it can be due to a powerbreak or a hard reset, or after a system hang caused by anything), and `chkdsk` can repair it. The problem is that if you can not start Windows, then it is tricky to run `chkdsk`, thats why you may need a bootable CD.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the F8 key on power up. If you can get as far as the menu, select the option to start using the "Last Known Good Configuration". If that doesn't work reboot and use F8 again but this time boot into safe mode and check your device manager for problems. If that's OK, try right clicking on your c: drive, select tools and scan for errors.